# Обращение к элементу по id

Tags: javascript

Обычно в литературе для доступа к элементу рекомендуют использовать `document.getElementById("id_")`.

Например, изменить ширину элемента:

```
<div id=scroller><div>
```

Я пишу:

```
document.getElementById("scroller").width = "100px";
```

Но часто встречаю исходники, где к элементу обращаются по `id` непосредственно так:

```
scroller.width = "100px";
```

Насколько это правильно и допустимо?

Comment: у вас получалось так обратиться к элементу?

Comment: да, как ни странно. Вполне

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Если элементу назначен специальный атрибут id, то можно получить его прямо по переменной с именем из значения id. Это поведение соответствует стандарту . Оно существует, в первую очередь, для совместимости, как осколок далёкого прошлого и не очень приветствуется, поскольку использует глобальные переменные. Браузер пытается помочь нам, смешивая пространства имён JS и DOM, но при этом возможны конфликты. Более правильной и общепринятой практикой является доступ к элементу вызовом document.getElementById("идентификатор")"

"Язык JavaScript. Часть 2",  Илья Кантор, 2015 г

Answer (score 2):

```
var scroller = document.getElementById("scroller")
scroller.width = "100px";
```

Делается это для удобства и организации кода, если например вы обращается к элементу `scroller` несколько раз.