# Правильное оформление стилей в js

Tags: javascript

Как более правильно менять стили в js,

Напрямую (1способ) или через поиск в документе (2способ) ?

Как будет грамотней?

```js
main.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';    // 1 cпособ
document.querySelector("#main").style.backgroundColor = 'blue';  // 2 способ
```

```html
<div id="main">
Опа
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обращение к элементу по id](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763566/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be-id)

Comment: Там про getElementById, а у меня другое.

Comment: какая разница? точно так же это относится к `querySelector`

Comment: А если у меня будет класс вместо id, то ваш getElementById не поможет(

Comment: почему мой? суть в том, чтобы сравнить обращение через метод (чаще всего с созданием переменной с любым именем, если придется обращаться к элементу не один раз) со сравнением обращения к элементу через специальную переменную, которая не объявлена явно, а генерируется движком браузера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2-ой способ использовать лучше. Первый же способ лучше не использовать. Это поведение соответствует стандарту, но поддерживается в основном для совместимости, как осколок далёкого прошлого.
Браузер пытается помочь нам, смешивая пространства имён JS и DOM. Это удобно для простых скриптов, которые находятся прямо в HTML, но, вообще говоря, не очень хорошо. Возможны конфликты имён. Кроме того, при чтении JS-кода, не видя HTML, непонятно, откуда берётся переменная.

Вы можете сделать так если вам будет удобнее

```js
const main = document.getElementById('main')
main.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

```html
<div id="main">
        Опа
        </div>
```

Comment: Я использовал querySelector("#main") а вы getElementById он лучше, чем  querySelector?

Comment: @Новичок `querySelector` это более новый метод, он универсальнее, почитайте про оба метода на MDN

Comment: Ну тогда я буду использовать querySelector, чем getElementById )

Comment: @Новичок я бы на вашем месте почитал бы про все детали, чтобы разобраться

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, хотел уточнить, значит прежде чем изменить стиль в js, мне в большинстве случаев нужно использовать document.querySelector(elem).style и тд ?

Comment: Кажется, я понял, что вы хотели сказать. Нужно использовать это через переменную? Если да, то что дает использование стилей через переменную?

Comment: @Новичок не обязательно делать это через переменную. Но если вы будете использовать элемент в коде снова то без использования переменной(к примеру писать так везде ```document.querySelector("#main").style...```) это может сказаться на оптимизации сайта. То есть если с переменной он просто найдёт элемент и будет его изменять,а если использовать постоянно ```document.querySelector("#main").style...``` то он будет для каждого изменения стиля заново искать элемент по всему сайту.

Comment: Вот это да, а я не знал. Значит буду использовать это с переменной. А чем переменная const лучше let ?

Comment: А почему вы разделили document.getElementById('main') и main.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';  на две строки?
Не лучше ли это написать в одну строку document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';  или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: @Новичок 1) переменные let и const не влияют на оптимизацию, они различны только тем ,что const нельзя менять ,а let можно. И если какой-нибудь программист захочет изменить const переменную,  то получит ошибку.

2) Я же говорю ситуация та же ,что и с ```document.querySelector("#main").style...``` . Я "разделил" их для того ,чтобы 1 раз сделать поиск элемента по сайту и засунул в переменную. И теперь в будущем моему коду не нужно будет искать этот элемент по всему сайту т.к он уже лежит в переменной, и я смогу использовать эту переменную в будущем